How can i preserve changes in main branch that are deleted and committed in feature branch in git?
I have main branch and feature branch, feature branch is created from main
branch.
Mistakenly some lines of code got deleted and committed in feature branch due to merging of branches.
Example:
main branch:
f1();
f2();
f3();

feature branch:
f1();
f3();

I have tried like this.
git checkout feature
git pull origin main

This is not getting deleted code.
If i raise pull request from feature to main and merge it will delete existing code.
How can i solve this problem??
Thanks,

If the error is in the feature branch, then you should fix the feature branch before you merge it. Introducing fixes of this kind in a merge commit leads to all sorts of question marks later. (Like: "These lines were removed in the commit over there, why are they back in the project?")

"Mistakenly some lines of code got deleted and committed in feature" get them "undeleted" directly in the feature branch. Revert commits if need be. Checkout out older versions of files and commit them on top of feature. Fix your mistake.

Git will not do it automatically for you, because your problem in a generic way is impossible to solve.
For example consider this file in main branch:
f1()
f2()
f3()

And you have this feature branch:
f1()
f2()
f4()

How may you say that f3() is removed mistakenly so we should bring it back, or f3() is renamed to f4()?
There is no generic solution for this problem, so you need to handle situation manually.
Use git diff to find all removed lines and check them one-by-one, and bring them back if they are deleted mistakenly.
